# Como pegar uma determinada variavel php que esta dentro da view no controller

Tags: codeigniter

Bom dia eu tenho uma pagina em php que está dentro da pasta view no codeigniter, lá eu possuo um foreach que estou listando o alfabeto e eu queria pegar essa variavel($letra) dentro do controller. Alguem pode me ajuda?
   Essa e a minha pagina dentro da view:

```
 <!-- Navigation -->
        <div class="titulo"><img alt="Logo" src="<?php echo base_url('midias/Logo.png')?>" /></div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <?php foreach(range('A', 'Z') as $letra) {?>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><?php print $letra;?><span class="caret"></span></a>
                           <form method="post"> <input type="hidden" name="inicial"  value="<?php echo $letra;?>" /></form>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                               <?php foreach ($listar as $lista):?>
                               <li><a href="#"><?php echo $lista['nome_categoria']?></a></li>
                               <?php endforeach;?> 
                            </ul>
                         </li>
                    </ul>
                    <?php }?>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            <!-- /.container -->
        </nav>
```

e esse e o meu controller:

```
<?php
class Index_controller extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $alfabeto['l'] =  $_POST['alfabeto'];
        echo $alfabeto['l'];
        $this->load->model('categoria_model','model',true);
        $alfabeto['listar'] = $this->model->listar($alfabeto['l']);
        $this->load->view('menu',$alfabeto);
        $this->load->view('home');
    }

}
```

---

O que eu quero fazer, criei um select que possui um like que esta recebendo um paramentro dentro do meu model

```
public function listar($letra){
        $this->db->select('nome_categoria');
        $this->db->from('categoria');
        $this->db->like('nome_categoria',$letra,'after');
        return $this->db->get()->result_array();
    }
```

ai eu pego esse model no cotroller assim:

```
public function index(){

        $this->load->helper('form');

        $this->load->model('categoria_model','model',true);

        $alfabetoNoController = range('A', 'Z'); // :)

        $alfabeto['alfabeto'] = $alfabetoNoController;
        $alfabeto['letra'] = null;
        $alfabeto['listar'] = $this->model->listar($alfabeto['letra']);//aqui estou pegando o model com o parametro
        $this->load->view('menu', $alfabeto);
        $this->load->view('home');
}
```

ai esse $alfabeto['letra'] tem que vim do foreach que acontence la na view, que possui um $letra, esse aqui:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
    <div class="titulo"><img alt="Logo" src="<?php echo base_url('midias/Logo.png')?>" /></div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <?php foreach($alfabeto as $letra)//eu tenho que pega essa letra aqui, mas nao sei como {?>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><?php print $letra;?><span class="caret"></span></a>
                       <form method="post"> <input type="hidden" name="alfabeto"  value="<?php echo $letra;?>" /></form>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                           <?php foreach ($listar as $lista):?>
                           <li><a href="#"><?php echo $lista['nome_categoria']?></a></li>
                           <?php endforeach;?> 
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                </ul>
                <?php }?>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Editado]**

Note que o teu html usa o `name=inicial`:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="inicial"  value="<?php echo $letra;?>" />
```

Mas o `$_POST['alfabeto']` usa a chave `alfabeto`, quando o correto deveria ser inicial.

Então o View pode continuar igual ao seu original:

```
                <?php foreach(range('A', 'Z') as $letra) {?>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><?php print $letra;?><span class="caret"></span></a>
                       <form method="post"> <input type="hidden" name="inicial"  value="<?php echo $letra;?>" /></form>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                           <?php foreach ($listar as $lista):?>
                           <li><a href="#"><?php echo $lista['nome_categoria']?></a></li>
                           <?php endforeach;?> 
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                </ul>
                <?php }?>
```

E o controller deve ficar assim:

```
<?php
class Index_controller extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){
        $this->load->helper('form');

        $alfabeto['l'] =  $_POST['inicial'];
        echo $alfabeto['l'];
        $this->load->model('categoria_model','model',true);
        $alfabeto['listar'] = $this->model->listar($alfabeto['l']);

        $this->load->view('menu',$alfabeto);
        $this->load->view('home');
    }
}
```

<s>Você pode criar o loop range dentro do Controller e depois enviar ao View:</s>

```
<?php
class Index_controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');

        $alfabeto['l'] =  $_POST['alfabeto'];

        echo $alfabeto['l'];

        $this->load->model('categoria_model','model',true);

        $alfabetoNoController = range('a', 'z'); // :)

        $alfabeto['listar'] = $this->model->listar($alfabeto['l']);
        $alfabeto['alfabeto'] = $alfabetoNoController;

        $this->load->view('menu', $alfabeto);

        //Se quiser fazer algo com ele no controller use o foreach
        foreach($alfabetoNoController as $letra) {
              //Algo aqui...
        }

        $this->load->view('home');

    }
}
```

E o View ficaria assim:

```
 <!-- Navigation -->
    <div class="titulo"><img alt="Logo" src="<?php echo base_url('midias/Logo.png')?>" /></div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <?php foreach($alfabeto as $letra) {?>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><?php print $letra;?><span class="caret"></span></a>
                       <form method="post"> <input type="hidden" name="inicial"  value="<?php echo $letra;?>" /></form>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                           <?php foreach ($listar as $lista):?>
                           <li><a href="#"><?php echo $lista['nome_categoria']?></a></li>
                           <?php endforeach;?> 
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                </ul>
                <?php }?>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

Comment: mas como eu pego o $letra dentro do controller?

Comment: @danielsilva perai você quer `range('a', 'z') as $letra` ou você quer pegar uma letra especifica? Porque `$letra` é usada dentro do loop e no final ele sempre vai pegar o `z`.

Comment: Mas como você quer estruturar isto no Controller, o `range` gera um array, e você pode acessar um a um assim `$alfabetoNoController[0]`, vai depender da onde você quer colocar no controller, porque se for pra ele ficar voando não faz diferença alguma, veja editei a resposta. Acredito que o problema seja que talvez você não tenha entendido bem o que é array. @danielsilva

Comment: como eu faço para esse $alfabetoNoController[0], ser dinamico?

Comment: `$alfabetoNoController[0]` pra você entender como o array é acessivel, você viu a edição da minha resposta? É isto o que quer? `        $alfabeto['alfabeto'] = $alfabetoNoController;

        $this->load->view('menu', $alfabeto);

        //Se quiser fazer algo com ele no controller use o foreach
        foreach($alfabetoNoController as $letra) {
              //Algo aqui...
        }` --- Uma array é como se fosse um conjunto de variaveis. @danielsilva

Comment: mas como eu passo $letra dinamicamente para o $this->model->listar(aqui dentro);

Comment: @danielsilva isto você não mencionou na pergunta, veja agora mudou o sentido, você quer é enviar o `range(a, z)` pra um model que é uma coisa diferente. No caso você enviou com POST não foi? Através de `$alfabeto['l'] =  $_POST['alfabeto'];`? Você quer passar uma letra selecionada pelo usuário pro model é isso?

Comment: e porque eu tenho um select que tem like que receber como parametro o $letra. Eu tentei criar um input hidden, mas nao sei com posso pegar ele no controller tambem, ja tentei atraves do $this->input->name();. Mas nao deu certo

Comment: Então teu problema não é pegar o `$letra` e sim pegar o `$_POST` estou correto?

Comment: sim, queria pegar no $_post

Comment: @danielsilva acho que encontrei o problema, editei a resposta.

Comment: Agora ele nao ta o erro Undefined index: inicial

Comment: @danielsilva vou ser sincero, eu acho que o erro já acontecia com `$_POST['alfabeto']`, pois isto é um POST, a não ser que você tenha forçado um valor pra `$_POST['alfabeto'] = 'y';` em algum lugar do teu código. Recomendo que use `empty` ou `isset` pra verificar se o envio veio por POST. Amigo sinceramente não da pra entender o objetivo do teu código e por isto fica dificil responder. Recomendo que edite a pergunta tentando colocar o teu objetivo com o código.